# Change the datasource of widget in a Wordpress theme

Tags: widgets

i have a wordpress theme and i want to change the data that is displayed on a widget.

My theme is `Bloom` from Famethemes ThemeForest and the widget is this

[image]

I need to diplay in the tabs a rss feed for which one. What do i have to change? Can i do it on the administration panel?

Comment: Support for specific theme or plugin is off-topic here.

Comment: @songdogtech, my question is about the widget and where can I change the information that appears on it . I wonder if it can be changed by the source code or something like that

Comment: Of course it can be changed. Show some code; what have you tried? Read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @songdogtech I made the mistake of asking without having tried to change the source code first. I will try to carry out this change as soon as you get home and edit the question with the generated code. sorry I did not read the topics that can be posted here.

Answer (score 0):

That's a commercial theme, so it's best to ask in the support forum where you bought the theme. Few people here will have the same theme. And, third-party themes and plugins are off topic here on WP-Dev.

Comment: i've ask on the famethemes support and they said than they not support it